# How to unescape `&#xA0;` in Node

Tags: node.js, escaping

I have some screen scrapping code like this...

```
request(options, function(error, response, html){
  console.log("Request complete");
  if(!error){
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var x = $('.updatebodytest');
    console.log(x.html());
    var y = x.find('th');
    var results = [];
    y.each(function(){
      console.log(querystring.unescape($(this).html()));
      results.push($(this).html());
    });
  }
})
```

The problem is I am getting an output that looks like `My&#xA0;Entity` in the console. How do I unescape this? Is this something other than HTML encoding?

Comment: Also what ended up helping me was using .text() instead of .html() in CherrioJs. Dope!

Answer (score 2):

Those are HTML entities. The built-in `querystring` module does not support those of course, but there are modules on npm such as [`he`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) which can decode such entities.